# Finding isomorphism between two permutation groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $G_1 = <(123)(45)>$ and $G_2 = \{e, (12)(34), (567), (576), (12)(34)(567), (12)(34)(576)\}$. I want to find an isomorphism between $G_1$ and $G_2$. I already know that:

(1 2 3)(4 5) $\rightarrow$ (1 2)(3 4)(5 6 7)

(1 3 2) $\rightarrow$ (5 7 6)

(4 5) $\rightarrow$ (1 2)(3 4)

(1 2 3) $\rightarrow$ (1 2)(3 4)(5 6 7)

(1 3 2)(4 5) $\rightarrow$ (5 7 6)

e $\rightarrow$ e

I usually find isomorphism between two groups by creating multiplication tables for each group and finding the patterns, but apparently this process is tedious and time-consuming if there are many elements. Is there an efficient way to find isomorphism in this case?

Comment: Use the orders of the elements. If the image of $g$ is $h$ then the image of $g^2$ is $h^2$ etc. As $G_1$ is cyclic, you only need test each possible image of its generator.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a:=(1\,2\,3)(4\,5)$, then $G_1=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5\}\ $ and $a^6=e$.
Let $b:=(1\,2)(3\,4)(5\,6\,7)$, then - as you calculated -
we have 
$$b^2=(5\,7\,6),\ \ b^3=(1\,2)(3\,4),\ \ b^4=(5\,6\,7),\ \ b^5=b^{-1}=(1\,2)(3\,4)(5\,7\,6)$$
So that $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ are both cyclic subgroups of order $6$, and sending the generator to generator, namely $a\mapsto b$, will uniquely extend to a homomorphism, as it necessarily satisfies $a^k\mapsto b^k$ for every $k\in\Bbb Z$, and this homomorphism is clearly bijective, hence is an isomorphism.